# Why does EF populate with null values a Entity that does not exist in Database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

When I try to retrieve a entity from database that have relationships, but in fact, all relationships are null, the EntityFramework populates the relationship with null values, instead of setting relationship to null.

Why does it happens? There's any way to avoid this pattern?

Example:

```
public class Entity{
    public Int32 ID {get;set;}

    public Relationship relationship {get;set;}
}

public class Relationship{
    public Int32 ID {get;set;}

    public Int32 property {get;set;}
}
```

If I try, without having a Relationship inside the database:

```
Entity entity = context.entities.Include("relationship").SingleOrDefault( e => e.ID == id);
```

I can access entity.relationship without triggering a NullReferenceException, but the property "property" is null.

Thanks,

Igor

Comment: I'm pretty sure that property "property", being an Int32, cannot be null. How are you sure this is the offending property?

Comment: It is certainly not a standard pattern. I similar situations I get EntityCollections with zero items. Is your code working code or is it a substitute for the real thing? If so, maybe you could show the actual code where it happens?

Comment: @dtryon, let's suppose so, that "property"is Int32. But that's not the point... If the entity doesn't exist in the database, why I can access the "property"?

Comment: @GertArnold, the code I posted is only an example... But my real code is pretty the same... The difference is that the classes has more relationships and properties... And I use several Includes to load all relationships...

Comment: @igor.araujo - You can access it because it's an Int32, not a nullable Int32.  Int32 can't be null, therefore when the class is created it must contain a value, that value will be the default value which is 0.

Comment: @MystereMan but that's exactly the point! The class should not be created at first... Because it do not exist!

Comment: What he is saying is that entity.relationship should not be created. I.E. entity.relationship == null (or should), so entity.relationship.property should throw a Null Reference Exception because he will be trying to access properties of relationship, when relationship is null

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say.  It sounds like entity.Relationship IS null.  You say you can access it fine, which is expected.  The property just returns null... which is exactly what you say when you try to do entity.Relationship.property... the null ref is there because you're trying to read .property on .Relationship which is null.  It almost sounds like you think you shouldn't be able to use a reference at all which is null... that wouldn't really work though.

Comment: @Andy, if the relationship is null, I shouldn't be able to access entity.relationship.property, right?... That should trigger a NullReferenceException! The point of the whole thing is that relationship SHOULD be NULL (because there's no relationship inside the database, the entity was persisted WITHOUT a relationship (null relationship) )... But it isn't!

Comment: Well, you're doing something wrong.  Unless you include a real example, that we can compile to see the problem.. we can't help you understand why you are seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: @igor.araujo No, if relationship is `null` the property is still part of the class, it just has a value of `null`.  Are you expecting an exception to be thrown just for looking at the property?  That would be extrodinarly bad design.  This is one of those cases where returning `null` is appropriate.  The only case where I'd expect a NRE is when you're accessing entity.Relationship and `entity` itself is null.

Comment: @MystereMan I don't think anything is wrong; I think igor is just expected a NullRefException simply for trying to access entity.Relationship.

Comment: @Andy, so my logic is wrong... To me, if some instance of Entity class do not have the relationship, it should be null and if you try to access it, it should trigger the Exception.. Like, hey, I don't exist man, you can't access my properties. Not that I want a NullReferenceException to be thrown, but I thought that I could check if the class has the relationship: if (entity.relationship == null)...

Comment: @Andy - No, he is expecting `entity.Relationship` to be null, but he says it isn't even though there is no related row in the database.  His NRE he is expecting is by doing `entity.Relationship.property` which he says doesn't generate an execption in his code.

Comment: @igor.araujo Your wording continues to confuse "if some instance of Entity class do not have the relationship, it should be null and if you try to access it, it should trigger the Exception"  I've been taking "it" to mean entity.Relationship, when you seem to be meaning entity.Relationship.Property.  I understand now, and yes, I would think that `entity.Relationship == null` would be `true`.

Comment: @MystereMan Yes, it seems I was a bit confused.  In my defense the question is a bit confusing the way its worded.  I'll suggest an edit.

Comment: @igor.araujo - I will repeat.  You should include a *REAL* complete example of the problem in your question, not a partial made-up one. If we're going to help you, we need to see exactly what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @igor.araujo After executing the query you provide the relationship navigation property will be null if no related entity exists in the database. If it isn't, then a related entity does exist. Can you explain how you can be sure of your assertion that no related entity exists in the database?

Comment: Maybe I've found the problem. As Mystere Man said, I forgot to put some "cards on the desk". I do not have time right now... But when I have, I'll post what I was doing "wrong". And @ajcvickers, I know that because it's my database... I verified the tables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're not really showing the whole story.  In order for there to be a `Relationship` navigation property, there must exist an ID that keys that relationship.  So your class has to look something like this:

```
public class Entity{ 
    public Int32 ID {get;set;} 

    public Int32? RelationshipID {get; set;}
    public Relationship relationship {get;set;} 
}
```

If RelationshipID is not null, then a Relationship object is created.  If the value of RelationshipID does not correspond to an actual data item, then this is an error and it should throw an exception.

If RelationshipID is null, then so will relationship be null.

The exception to this is when it's a 1 to many, in which case it will be an ICollection and relationship will not be null, but it will be an empty collection, and there will be no RelationshipID (the ID will be held in the related item).

You can't have a relationship without some kind of key.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty new in ASP .NET MVC. Maybe I'm doing it wrong all along... But I never have declared the relationships IDs as a properties of my classes (I thought it was automatic). I started learning by reading the asp.net tutorials... And I do not remeber this kind of "pattern" in those tutorials.

Comment: @igor.araujo - This has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC, this is an Entity Framework related question.  EF and MVC are different technologies.  The ID is necessary, otherwise the framework would have no idea how to lookup the navigation property.  It has to know what the foreign key is.

Comment: @igor.araujo - It's not like you can "do it wrong".  EF won't even work if you don't define the foreign key ID field, it will just generate an error telling you you need the ID.  It will say something like "Unable to retrieve association information for association 'item'. Only models that include foreign key information are supported."

Comment: @Mystere_Man, I meant that I'm pretty new with the .NET Framework (my mistake)... I've faced that error once or more... And, in fact, I was forced to define a Foreign Key. But not always, not in every model... And I don't know how it has worked, but it has.

Comment: @Mystere_Man, I'll, then, define a foreign key to every one of my models... Let's see if I manage to solve my problem. Then, if I load the relationship, to know if it's null, I need only to look at the foreign key? (in your answer, check if RelationshipID == null?)

Comment: @Mystere Man: EF does not require that the foreign key be included in the object model. In other words, the RelationshipID property is not required. Assuming Code First, then if it is not present Code First will create an "independent association".

Comment: @ajcvickers - independent associations are not generally used these days.  They were in V1, while the more important Foreign Key relationships are what should be used.  You're right that it's possible, but not advised.  Also, if you do this with code first, you need to explicitly define the relationship either through fluent api or attributes.

Comment: @MystereMan: Agreed that FK assoications are generally recommended. However, you don't need to explicitly define IAs through the fluent API or attributes. If Code First doesn't find an FK property by convention or configuration, then it will create an IA and generate a column name for the FK backing it.

Comment: @ajcvickers - that's not what EF tells me when i try to use them, it says the have to be explicitly defined.

Comment: @MystereMan: Interesting; maybe you have found a bug. When I use the two classes exactly as defined in the question with no additional configuration on EF 4.3, I get an IA generated in the model mapped to an FK in the database called "relationship_ID". This is certainly what is supposed to happen. What do you get? If you can generate a repro then I'll investigate to see if I can find the bug.